# Timthumb.php image gallery not working on Multisite Wordpress

Tags: php, multisite, gallery, timthumb, images

What I am trying to do is get a gallery working on a multisite wordpress installation . . It works on the home site because that is where wordpress is actually installed but not on the sub domain sites. Timthumb.php is a script that basically resizes images into a thumbnail. So on main domain it works but not on any subdomains, it doesn't show the thumb, only the main image once the thumb is clicked.

The creator of timthumb.php wrote a fix at http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2009/10/timthumb-wordpress-mu/ but I cannot work out the application for my case. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

TimThumb is enough of a resource drain on a non-network install; I can only imagine how much more of a resource drain it would be on a network install.

Rather than trying to make TimThumb work on your network install, why not just use the core Post Thumbnail functionality? TimThumb is absolutely unnecessary in WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and tried the binarymoon fix... but it never worked out for me. But, I found this fix!

http://wpcodesnippets.info/blog/how-to-use-timthumb-php-with-multisites.html

Just copy paste the timbthumb.php file with the mulitsite fix in it and you should be good to go. Good Luck.

Comment: Please post relevant code in your answer in the future. The link provided is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

http://odotteeaux.com/blog/2011/02/14/timthumb-php-fix-for-wordpress-mu/

http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2009/10/timthumb-wordpress-mu/

This will solve your problem IA

Comment: You should provide actual code or a solution in your answer and not just links. The first one is dead.